# How to do the equivalent of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` using Ansible's `apt` module?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, apt, ubuntu-server

I'm having difficulty configuring Ansible's `apt` module so that it does the exact equivalent of the following command line:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

My best attempt so far is this:

```
- name: update and upgrade packages
  apt:
    force_apt_get: yes
    name: "*"
    only_upgrade: yes
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
```

However, this keeps installing packages I have previously removed using `sudo apt-get remove [name]`.

How can I tell Ansible to upgrade exactly only those packages which are already installed?

I'm using Ansible 2.8.4 with Python 3.7.4. The remote is a Ubuntu Server 18.4.3. Everything works fine when running the apt-get commands manually.

Answer (score 0):

I must suggest you not to use `force_apt_get: yes` in your playbook. As Ansible has the apt module designed for just this purpose. I've done this using apt below.

In a playbook, you can update and upgrade like so:

```
- name: Update and upgrade apt packages
  become: true
  apt:
    upgrade: yes
    update_cache: yes
```

Furthermore you can also remove the dependencies that are no longer required.

```
- name: Remove useless packages from the cache
  apt:
     autoclean: yes

- name: Remove dependencies that are no longer required
  apt:
     autoremove: yes
```

Comment: I followed all your advice but the result stays the same: The packages I just had removed before get installed again.